# "is to make sure" vs "is making sure"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I've encountered both variants:

> My goal **is to make** sure we are safe.
>
> My goal **is making** sure we are safe.

Another example:

> His biggest challenge **is making** sure all the wood is legal.
>
> His biggest challenge **is to make** sure all the wood is legal.

In the American English Corpus "is to make sure" is three times more common than "is making sure." But beyond that is there a difference in usage or meaning?

Answer (score 2):

We need a [nominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_(linguistics)) (a word that can take on noun functions) to act as the complement of the copula *is*.  Both the infinitive ("to *verb*") and the gerund ("*verb*ing") serve this purpose, and provide the same grammatical meaning in this particular context.

To my native ear, the gerund sounds smoother, but the infinitive sounds more formal.

Comment: Hold on. So do we need a noun or not. Because a verb is clearly not a noun and so won't do.

Comment: The gerund and the infinitive are noun forms.  They [act like nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbal_noun).

Comment: The infinitive is a verb, by definition. Nouns don't have infinitives. Also, as someone else has just pointed out in chat, copulas don't have objects.

Comment: All I'm saying is this can be worded more carefully. And probably should.

Comment: Reg is right that copulae don't have direct objects: they have subject complements. Apart from that, the answer is fine. It is true that infinitives and gerunds can serve as nouns, because they can be both verb and noun at the same time (noun externally, verb internally).

Comment: @RegDwigнt Better?

Answer (score 1):

Surely the infinitive "**to make**" is a **clearer marker of purpose** than the **ing-form**.

Thus "**goal**" should have been part of  your search, for at Google Books:

"goal is to make sure"
About 258,000 results

"goal is making sure"
About 232 results

Much more unbalanced in favor to "to make" in this context.